# raise() of signal is not waking a sleeping process

Tags: c, linux, signals

I have a single thread program that sleeps to conserve battery power while waiting for hardware events. main() registers a signal handler, then sleeps.  Hardware interrupt handlers may wake main by calling a function which calls raise(), and seeing any signal should wake main from sleep.

Now, for development purposes, I am running on a desktop, and instead of getting true hardware events, there are a couple of other processes which send fake hardware events.  Instead of the interrupt handler making the aforementioned function calls, these tasks do.

A very simple demo case works fine, I can provide that code if needed, but don't want this post to be too long.

I have declared this signal handler:

```
void sig_handler( int signo )
{
    //To confirm that this process is the same one that is sleeping
    printf("sig_handler: my PID is %d\n", getpid());

    if ( SIGUSR1 == signo)
    {
        printf("received SIGUSR1\n");
    }
    else
    {
       printf("received some other signal\n");
    }
}
```

There is lot of other code, but the bit in question is that during init, I call:

```
sSigAction.sa_handler = sig_handler;
sigemptyset( &sSigAction.sa_mask );
sigaction( SIGUSR1, &sSigAction, NULL );
```

In a function called by another process (or interrupt handler in real system):

```
printf( "raising signal!\n");
raise( SIGUSR1 );
```

In main:

```
printf("main: my PID is %d\n", getpid());
while(1)
{
    printf("sleeping forever\n");
    usleep(-1);
    printf("main is awake"\n);
    //Do work we were waiting to do
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
main: my PID is 17250
sleeping forever
raising signal!
sig_handler: my PID is 17250
received SIGUSR1
```

Note the critical lack of "main is awake".  As I said, doing these same steps does work, in a simple demo case. Since I am doing the same setup, I don't understand why it's not working.  In both cases, I perform the same signal handler registration, usleep(), and raise(), but the demo case works and this does not.

Any ideas of what I could be missing?

Follow-up:  I have found that if I use $kill -s USR1    then the task wakes as expected.  So the mechanism is sound, but why does $kill work and raise() not?

Follow-up 2: I now have the function calling raise() also print getpid() and it matches the PID of main().

---

Resolution:  While in the end I will have a single thread, and raise() would be appropriate right now I have multiple, and so must use kill(). It's that simple.

Comment: `raise()` sends the signal to its own process, not some other process. So calling it in another process won't interrupt this process.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I had the function calling raise() print its PID, and that matches the PID of main().

Comment: Exactly what @Barmar said. To send the signal from another process, you need to use `kill(2)`. Also, you should zero out the `sa_flags` field of `struct sigaction` before calling `sigaction(2)` to set up the handler (else the program has UB because `sigaction(2)` will attempt to read an uninitialized field). Finally, `pid_t` is not guaranteed to fit in an `int`, but it is guaranteed to fit in a `long`, so you should use `%ld` to print it (and cast the result of `getpid(2)` to `long`).

Comment: Your question says you call `raise()` "In a function called by another process". If it's a different process, how can have the same PID as `main()`? Maybe you're misusing the word "process".

Comment: But it seems like your real question is "Why doesn't `usleep` return after the signal handler executes?"

Comment: How can you have the same process call `raise(3)` if it is sleeping? Is it another thread?

Comment: You are aware that `printf()` is not async-safe, right?

Comment: Yes, thanks, guys.  I feel stupid.  I am in the end developing a single-threaded application, but yes, right now it's multi-threaded and I need to use kill() rather than raise().  It's that simple.

Comment: As for printf(), yes - in fact I'm calling a log function which has  semaphore around it, I typed printf here to avoid having to explain that, heh

Comment: @Jason: You realize that in a *multithreaded* program `kill()` is virtually useless, since you can't target individual threads?

Comment: @EOF  But kill() takes __pid_t as a parameter

Comment: ...and all threads in a multithreaded process share their pid. Your point?

Comment: Yeah, you're right - in this case it's not important, as there is only the one signal handler, and the other threads are only there temporarily.

Comment: ...and all threads share signal handlers. Your point?

Comment: Right, so I switched to pthread_kill.  Thanks :)

Comment: That's nice. Also, using semaphores (or other non-lockfree synchronization) in a signal handler is undefined (will likely result in deadlock).